# RadComboBoxItem hide() on client-side not persisting

Tags: asp.net, telerik-combobox

**What are you doing?**

Using a RadComboBox, I'm hiding items from the user view under certain conditions.

**What's the problem?**

The combo items hide perfectly, however, when I click the combo box and then click anywhere else on the page (in other words, loose focus after focusing on the combobox) all the items I have hidden become visible again.

**What else have you tried?**

Thinking maybe I am not using the Telerik RadCombo Client Side API correctly, I decided to check whether deleted or disabled items would also magically re-appear when focusing and unfocusing from the RadComboBox.

The result; this issue only happens when hiding items, not when deleting or disabling RadComboBox items.

**Demo of problem**

For clarity and convenience, I've setup a page which very simply demonstrates the problem. 
Download [TestRadComboItemHide.zip](http://www.ping24.com/downloads/TestRadComboItemHide.zip) and extract TestRadComboItemHide.aspx.

Place this ASPX into a website/webapp project and run ensuring you have telerik dll in the bin or Telerik installed on your dev computer.

**Additional info**

1. I've requsted assistance on Telerik support forums. (24 hours ago,
   nothing helpful response as yet)
2. Using RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q1 2010: 2010.1.415.40

Comment: telerik is a pain in the ass, IMO. Lot of workarounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [work around](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/radcomboboxitem-hide-on-client-side-not-persisting.aspx) to the problem is posted on the telerik forums. The solution was provided by another forum member, not Telerik.